# Passing dynamic values in command line

Tags: ruby, command-line, cron

I'm trying to pass dynamic values in command line for a ruby script.

```
ruby file_name.rb '2016-10-11' '2016-10-12'
```

The 2 date parameters need to be passed dynamically and this script sits inside a cron job.

Can someone help me in passing the date parameters dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean “passed dynamically”? They are already passed dynamically. Do you need kinda “today” and “tomorrow”?

Comment: Yes, I need a variable there which by default takes today and yesterday

Comment: Why won’t you get defaults (for `cron`’s sake) _inside your ruby script_? The question still is quite unclear. Please describe the use-case in details, also **share the effort you have already put it**.

Comment: @FirstName you need `array` of 2 dates, like `dates = ['2016-10-11','2016-10-12']` or ?

Answer (score 2):

To get today and yesterday dates in the shell in the format given, one uses:

```
date +%Y-%m-%d
#⇒ 2016-12-22
date --date yesterday +%Y-%m-%d
#⇒ 2016-12-21
```

To put those to the `cron`:

```
ruby file_name.rb `date --date yesterday +%Y-%m-%d` `date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

Note the backticks. One might check the actual command to be performed:

```
echo "ruby file_name.rb `date --date yesterday +%Y-%m-%d` `date +%Y-%m-%d`"
#⇒ ruby file_name.rb 2016-12-21 2016-12-22
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set default dates inside your Ruby script when no parameter is given :

```
require 'date'

def get_date(date, default_date = Date.today)
  if date
    Date.parse(date)
  else
    default_date
  end
end

date1 = get_date(ARGV.shift, Date.today - 1) # defaults to yesterday
date2 = get_date(ARGV.shift, Date.today)     # defaults to today

puts date1
puts date2
```

This way, you can shift the logic from cron/bash to ruby, but can still override parameters if needed :

```
ruby file_name.rb
# 2016-12-21
# 2016-12-22

ruby file_name.rb '2016-10-11'
# 2016-10-11
# 2016-12-22

ruby file_name.rb '2016-10-11' '2016-10-12'
# 2016-10-11
# 2016-10-12
```